# Filter a Group by Clause SQL

Tags: sql

Filter Group by clause to only show results where RPAN8 = 1

```
SELECT RPAN8, COUNT(RPVR01) As data 
FROM Test
GROUP BY RPAN8
HAVING RPAN8 = '1';
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off filtering *before* aggregating, which means using `WHERE`:

```
SELECT RPAN8, COUNT(RPVR01) As data
FROM Test
WHERE RPAN8 = '1'
GROUP BY RPAN8 ;
```

However, your version should work as well.

Comment: Looking to filter the group by results to 1 instance.